# Soapui Script Assertion, when Json response return as string

Tags: json, string, soapui, assertions

My Json response(which return as string),

```
"[{\"Serial\":5,\"Name\":\"hold\",\"Types\":[{\"Serial\":36,\"Id\":5,\"Data\":true}]}]"
```

My Script Assertion,

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)
//verify the slurper isn't empty
assert !(jsonSlurper.isEmpty())
assert jsonSlurper.Serial == 5
```

But I'm getting an error

"A JSON payload should start with an openning curly brace '{' or an openning square bracket '['.
Instead, '"[{\"Serial\":5,\"Name\":\"hold\",\"Types\":[{\"Serial\":36,\"Id\":5,\"Data\":true}]}]"' was found on line: 1, column: 1"

How to fix this script, I just want to assert that my response should not be empty and Serial is equal to 5.

Comment: The response is invalid; it *shouldn't* be a string. You'll have to fix the response on the server.

Comment: No its a valid Json response , I validated it using http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: As the error message says, it's *not* valid. `"[{\"sysSerial\":...` is invalid. It should be `[{"sysSerial":...` I'm pretty sure that if you paste the string into the jsonlint, it won't say it's valid. Don't double-encode it into a string!

Comment: Ah, sorry, of course it's valid JSON because it's a string. But it's not an object, and the payload is expected it to be an object.

Comment: It's not a question of converting it to an object. It's already an object but you stop (double-)converting it into a string. You'll have to show the code that generates the response.

Comment: I don't have code access. Any other way to resolve the issue as it is valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have fixed my own problem by simple regular expressions.

Here is the code guys,

```
//imports
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

//grab the response
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent

def TrimResponse =ResponseMessage.replaceAll('^\"|\"$','').replaceAll('^ \\[|\\]$','').replaceAll('\\\\','')

//define a JsonSlurper
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(TrimResponse)

//verify the slurper isn't empty
assert !(jsonSlurper.isEmpty())

assert jsonSlurper.Serial != null
assert jsonSlurper.Serial == 5
assert jsonSlurper.Types[0].Serial == 36
```

Enjoy :)